# Dual norm of $L_p$ space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $R^n$ is equipped with the norm $||x|| = (\sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_k|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ for some $p ≥ 1$, what is the induced norm on the conjugate (dual) space?

I couldn't figure out how to prove that the two norms here are essentially the same by proving the norm of dual space is bounded by two constants $a$ and $b$ of the norm given above (that's the norm of $L_p$ space for $p\geq 1$). Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent so the norm on $(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$ is **BOUNDED BY** (thanks Ian) a constant times any other norm on $(\Bbb{R}^n)^{\ast}$. Practically there's little need to know exactly what the constant is, but the dual norm of any $l^p$ norm is the $q$ norm where $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. Practically though, it's irrelevant.

Comment: You meant  "the norm on (ℝn)∗ is a constant times any other norm on (ℝn)"? Otherwise, great answer. Can you provide a shorter proof for proving "the dual norm of l^p is the q norm" than the one on page 3 in this link: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/600/l/l05a.pdf

Comment: @user177196 No I meant what I said. Since the dual of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is $\Bbb{R}^n$, what you say is also true. And no, not really. It's just what you have to do.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help:)

Comment: Your statement is not quite true. Norm equivalence means that each norm is bounded by some constant times the other norm. This does not make them equal to a constant times the other norm.

Comment: @Ian You are correct of course.